# Sending multipart Form in ReactJS vs Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a registration api that works fine using postman, I added some values there plus image an everything stores correctly, data an image, Later I started my React form and only text works, image is not currently sent to the api I guess.

Doing *console.log()* api in Node:

```
console.log(req.files);
```

- with React Form: []
- with Postman: an array of object that perfectly works

**req.files output using postman**

```
{
    fieldname: 'images',
    originalname: 'Screen Shot 2021-02-22 at 17.18.41.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: 'uploads/',
    filename: '091f77f82fb805b1ede9f23205cc578e',
    path: 'uploads/091f77f82fb805b1ede9f23205cc578e',
    size: 37052
  }
```

Here's my react classes:

**httpService.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
  const expectedError =
    error.response &&
    error.response.status >= 400 &&
    error.response.status < 500;

  if (!expectedError) {
    console.log("Loggind the error: ", error);
    toast("An unexpected error ocurred.");
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default {
  post: axios.post
};
```

**itemService.js**

```
export function saveItem(item) {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  };
  return http.post(MY_ENDPOINT, item, headers);
}
```

**itemForm.js**

```
import React from "react";

import Joi from "joi-browser";

import Form from "./common/form";
import { saveItem } from "../services/itemService";

class ItemForm extends Form {
  
  state = {
    data: { title: "", description: "", category: "", images: "" },
    categories: [],
    errors: {},
  };

  schema = {
    _id: Joi.string(),
    title: Joi.string().required().label("Title"),
    description: Joi.string().required().label("Description"),
    category: Joi.string().required().label("Category"),
    images: Joi.required().label("Image"),
  };

  doSubmit = async () => {
    console.log('form data> ', this.state.data); // This shows the correct object.
    
    let formData  = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', this.state.data.title);
    formData.append('description', this.state.data.description);
    formData.append('category', this.state.data.category);
    formData.append('images', this.state.data.images);

    try {
      await saveItem(formData);
    } catch (ex) {
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>New item</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderInput("title", "Title")}
          {this.renderInput("description", "Description")}
          {this.renderSelect(
            "category",
            "title",
            "Category",
            this.state.categories
          )}
          {this.renderInputFile("images", "images", "file", false)}
          {this.renderButton("Register")}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemForm;
```

**form.jsx (The extended class)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Input from "./input";
import Select from "./select";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    errors: {},
  };

  validate = () => {
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options);

    if (!error) return null;

    const errors = {};
    for (let item of error.details) errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
    return errors;
  };

  validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
    const obj = { [name]: value };
    const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };

    const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
    return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const errors = this.validate();
    this.setState({ errors: errors || {} });
    if (errors) return;

    this.doSubmit();
  };

  handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];

    const data = { ...this.state.data };
    data[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({ data, errors });
  };

  handleInputFileChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];

    const data = { ...this.state.data };
    data[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({ data, errors });
  };

  renderButton(label) {
    return (
      <button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={this.validate()}>
        {label}
      </button>
    );
  }

  renderInput(name, label, type = "text", multiple = false) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Input
        type={type}
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={errors[name]}
        multiple={multiple}
      />
    );
  }

  renderSelect(name, contentField, label, options) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        contentField={contentField}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={errors[name]}
      />
    );
  }

  renderInputFile(name, label, type = "text", multiple = false) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Input
        type={type}
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        onChange={this.handleInputFileChange}
        error={errors[name]}
        multiple={multiple}
        accept="image/*"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: what package are you using to submit the formData object in  itemService.js? ie. what's `http` and/or how is it being declared/imported ?

Comment: @tmilar I use axios. I've updated my post. I included the service class. Thanks!